# Sign up button on Talent redirects to home page

Tags: discussion, login

I am on Stack Overflow Talent, and I have two questions.

1. I tried to log in first, and it took me to the login page, but it seemed I am not a registered user, so then I tried to click on the <kbd>Sign-up</kbd> button, but that just redirects me abruptly to the home page.

[image]

2. It's not clear if the Talent platform is only for employer and not for job seekers. If it is only for the employer then any particular reason for it? And if it is for everyone then why does the sign-up button say "Build my employer brand"?

Comment: Don't Talents have its own support?

Comment: Anyway, you might have better luck by submitting a contact form, see the footer for "contact".

Answer (score 1):

In theory - the non 'public platform' products are supported by their own teams, though I'm not that sure that someone who can't create an account would be able to log a ticket for a service they can't use. That said, if you ask here, chances are someone on staff will notice and give it a look, even if this isn't 'strictly' the right place.

As for your second question

Well - Talent [changed its focus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/07/an-update-on-our-product-led-saas-transformation/) at some point, and the 'jobs'/'matching people who want a job with people who want to hire' business [has been sunset](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story). Essentially, it’s now a space for companies to let you know what they're like, like [Glassdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassdoor) without the comments section.

Comment: Well, if anything, this belongs to MSO. Talents got nothing to do with SE network, it's part of Stack Overflow the company.

Comment: on the other hand, SO really dosen't have that much to do with teams any more or talent so.... I'm not sure any more about those things :D